# How to assign self signed certificate to AWS elastick beanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We have developed web api using .net core 3.0 along with swagger. And, for testing purpose we have deployed this api on aws on EC2 instance using EBS. However, while deploying we have noticed that by default it takes only http, but we to expose the api using https.

So, for the same we have created self signed certificate on aws virtual machine and tried to configure to the hosted API and added bindings to Https by selecting the certificate. Our aws vm using IIS 10.

However, after doing this out api is stopped working and it gives lot of errors. We have tried to add the certificate in Certificate manager and after that modifying the load balancer also. But it doesn't seems to be working at all.

So, can anyone what exactly we are missing here? What are correct steps needs to be taken to configure self signed certificate to AWS deployment.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've typically done is put the SSL certificate on the load balancer, so the path essentially becomes:

https traffic -> Load Balancer (HTTPS Port, does handshake) -> Application (HTTP Port)

So essentially the user send an https request that is encrypted up to the load balancer, but the load balancer does the handshake for us and passes the packet off via HTTP inside our VPC.

Comment: Allow your application to accept traffic over only HTTP and configure the load balancer to accept traffic over HTTPS

Comment: But how you have created certificate? As i have done through VM using iis and then trying to configure to load balancer in aws console

Comment: I'm not super familiar with IIS, but I'd use the AWS ACM to generate and manage certificates.